# Can't connect to my server using SSH Kerberos Auth on OSX 10.7

Tags: ssh, osx-lion, kerberos

I just upgraded my Mac OS to 10.7 Lion. It has worked well before. But, only `kinit` working normally now, I can't ssh to my server.

After reinstalling the "Mac OS X Kerberos Extras", it didn't get better.

My command:

```
ssh root@10.3.18.211 -v

......

debug1: Authentications that can continue: gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1:  Miscellaneous failure (see text)
UNKNOWN_SERVER while looking up 'host/10.3.18.211@3.18.211' (cached result, timeout in 1200 sec)

debug1:  An invalid name was supplied
unknown mech-code 0 for mech 1 2 752 43 14 2

debug1:  Miscellaneous failure (see text)
unknown mech-code 0 for mech 1 3 6 1 5 5 14

debug1: Authentications that can continue: gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1:  An unsupported mechanism was requested
unknown mech-code 0 for mech 1 3 5 1 5 2 7

debug1:  Miscellaneous failure (see text)
unknown mech-code 0 for mech 1 3 6 1 5 2 5

debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@10.3.18.211's password:
```

Comment: its asking for the password at the end, is it failing if you use it, any output after that?

Comment: no output after that, it seems kerberos auth failed  or  timeout ...

Comment: for me this meant "run kinit username@REALM" http://betterlogic.com/roger/2015/01/kinit-wrong-realmhost/

Answer (score 7):

Do you have the following two lines in your `~/.ssh/config` file, or in your `/etc/ssh_config`?:

```
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPITrustDNS yes
```

The first is required to enable GSSAPI (Kerberos) authentication, the second one is required to get ssh to canonicalize the hostname via DNS and use the canonical name to obtain a host service ticket. Without the second one, ssh will use the exact hostname or IP address entered on the command line to try and obtain a host service ticket, and in this case it fails:

> UNKNOWN_SERVER while looking up 'host/10.3.18.211@3.18.211'

The actual name of the principal is normally 'host/hostname.domain@REALM' rather than an IP address. Of course, you need a correct reverse DNS setup for this to work.

It also seems like OS X can't detect the correct realm name to use and is trying to use an IP address instead (the '@3.18.211' part). Do you have correct DNS TXT and SRV records set up for your realm and KDC? If not you'll need to enter the default realm and KDC address manually in `/etc/krb5.conf`.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! Just add this line: `GSSAPITrustDNS yes` Everything work well now.

Comment: If something worked for you you should **mark the answer as accepted** using the checkmark below the score. I guess you will also have to link your accounts so that the question here belongs to you again.

Comment: This makes no change for me right now *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

I had these errors connecting to Centos, but not to fedora. **Solved by changing my User to a full userPrincipalName instead of my short name on OS X.**

~/.ssh/config:

```
Host svn saturnus.lan
User user@EXAMPLE.COM
```

**SSH unknown mech-code errors:**

```
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug2: we sent a gssapi-with-mic packet, wait for reply
debug1: Delegating credentials
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1:  An invalid name was supplied
unknown mech-code 0 for mech 1 2 752 43 14 2

debug1:  Miscellaneous failure (see text)
unknown mech-code 0 for mech 1 3 6 1 5 5 14

debug2: we sent a gssapi-with-mic packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1:  An unsupported mechanism was requested
unknown mech-code 0 for mech 1 3 5 1 5 2 7

debug1:  Miscellaneous failure (see text)
unknown mech-code 0 for mech 1 3 6 1 5 2 5

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
```